# How do we get Qt to render to memory rather than a device?

Tags: embedded, qt5, in-memory

I have an application that uses Qt 5.6 for various purposes and that runs on an embedded device. Currently I have it rendering via eglfs to a Linux frame buffer on an attached display but I also want to be able to grab the data and send it to a single-color LED display unit (a device will either have that unit *or* a full video device, never both at the same time).

Based on what I've found on the net so far, the best approach is to:

- turn off anti-aliasing;
- set Qt up for 1 bit/pixel display device;
- select a 1bpp font, no grey-scale allowed; and
- somehow capture the graphics scene that Qt produces so I can transfer it to the display unit.

It's just that last one I'm having issues with. I suspect I need to create a surface of some description and inject that into the Qt display "stack", but I cannot find any good examples on how to do this.

How does one do this and, assuming I have it right, is there a synchronisation method used to ensure I'm only getting complete buffers from the surface (i.e., no tearing)?

Comment: IIRC with QWS there was the feature to use dual frame buffer. Probably is available on Qt5  or higher with egfls.